# JPA Internationalized entity structure (Locale Translation)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to make data within my database international, so that it can be translated when required. Based on the model as illustrated below. How best to translate this to a JPA data structure. I would prefer not to use a hash map. Preferably I have a generic way of approach and not a database with a translation table for each entity.

Would any of you be able to help me with this?

Myself, I don't quite understand how to use an entity multiple times within one entity, as shown below.

```
@OneToOne()
public Locale name;

@OneToOne()
public Locale description;
```

[Plant uml diagram image](https:////www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/dPB1Yjim48RlUefPzvAKJSoMdam8sswxK6YXX-tPJAHf8YfBHXhHX99thnnCf6qtcEmSR6iq_pS_CxuFZ9vZPyIDjj94HR1ZxaDJrnv_BxUQTt4J0tdfB9FbfNHTtHkqWsOHM1czgH_UBxuFgH_VljOT1YQVKkr3Kg2sv9Vzm1StYdwc8p1k3CtsSv06Gu0zh5OmUxfzy_Zu8SKSrkjpQUzrX_xG_gB385Z5zNvLnxNOQKNG4U-S2a9yTD6gL3RRtDr2zUJH1eEidQtcy4S0mDWIZ9De24xPCRvyEd-cdXWDjmRjDkAMMgrETqTHCiRRYnIB7PqFqYbwWS7PuWNCQ3LPo9dIrXXCUnxvwI6oi6cqWkgkWiKYlPPlgx9dqsHwIVvFT8PT64rMJhGhPCToN-_IlZvRrgmf_BiizAnbChdrBlOmdnwseY2zxeUMUIRFCKqpABBJgXZNIzK5yeBesLw3yzpoeQTNsys8AQkvycgRqXddyuztlSaJODBWM3LjxYZkoQhOcRy0)

```
!include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML/master/C4_Container.puml

!define table(x) class x << (T,#FFAAAA) >>
!define primary_key(x) <u>x</u>
hide methods

Boundary(b1, "Translation") {
    table( locale ) {
        ID
        default_language_id
    }

    table( language ) {
        ID
        name
        code
    }

    table( translation ) {
        ID
        locale_id
        language_id
        text
    }
   
    locale::id "1" -- "1.*" translation::locale_id
    language::id "1" -- "1.*" locale::default_language_id
    language::id "1" -- "1.*" translation::language_id
}

Boundary(b2, "Entities") {
    table( article_group ){
        ID
        name
        description
    }
    article_group::name "1" -- "1" locale::id
    article_group::description "1" -- "1" locale::id


    table( sort_type ){
        ID
        name
        description
    }
    sort_type::name "1" -- "1" locale::id
    sort_type::description "1" -- "1" locale::id


    table( color ) {
         ID
        name
        description
    }
    color::name "1" -- "1" locale::id
    color::description "1" -- "1" locale::id
}
@enduml
```

Comment: it is bit unclear what is your actual goal: are you looking for "optimal" solution or just asking how to implement your schema design using JPA?

Comment: You need to use some sort of collection. After all, you have multiple translations. I would suggest using an element collection `@ElementCollection Map<Locale, NameDescription> localized;` where `NameDescription` is an embeddable.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I'm open for both, but I would also like to see how to implement the above schema using jpa.